# remove all rows with a character string ending with a specific string in R - grepl

Tags: r, grepl

I want to remove all rows that end with "_bundle". I tried two different things, but none if working

```
claimsVolumeSC <- basisPerClaim[!grepl( '$_bundle', basisPerClaim$subcoveragekey),]
levels(claimsVolumeSC$subcoveragekey)
claimsVolumeSC <- basisPerClaim[!grepl( '\\>_bundle', basisPerClaim$subcoveragekey),]
levels(claimsVolumeSC$subcoveragekey)
```

How can i achieve what i want ?
Why is what i have tried so far not working?

```
> claimsVolumeSC <- basisPerClaim[!grepl( '$_bundle', basisPerClaim$subcoveragekey),]
> levels(claimsVolumeSC$subcoveragekey)
[1] "DA_Chemo"         "Daily_cash"       "Funeral"          "IP_Accommodation" "IP_bundle"        "IP_Upgrade"       "OP_Dialysis"     
[8] "OP_Physio"       
> claimsVolumeSC <- basisPerClaim[!grepl( '\\>_bundle', basisPerClaim$subcoveragekey),]
> levels(claimsVolumeSC$subcoveragekey)
[1] "DA_Chemo"         "Daily_cash"       "Funeral"          "IP_Accommodation" "IP_bundle"        "IP_Upgrade"       "OP_Dialysis"     
[8] "OP_Physio"
```

Comment: `basisPerClaim[!grepl( '_bundle$', basisPerClaim$subcoveragekey),]`

Comment: i still get  > levels(claimsVolumeSC$subcoveragekey)
[1] "DA_Chemo"         "Daily_cash"       "Funeral"          "IP_Accommodation" "IP_bundle"        "IP_Upgrade"       "OP_Dialysis"     
[8] "OP_Physio"

Comment: Do you need them to be factors? You can convert them to characters `claimsVolumeSC$subcoveragekey <- as.character(claimsVolumeSC$subcoveragekey)`.

Comment: characters are fine, thanks i didnt notice ...this is working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `subset` with `grepl`

```
claimsVolumeSC <- subset(basisPerClaim, !grepl( '_bundle$', subcoveragekey))
```

If you don't want factors in data, change them to characters.

```
claimsVolumeSC$subcoveragekey <- as.character(claimsVolumeSC$subcoveragekey)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be this regex-based one:

**Reproducible data**:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  Var1 = rnorm(100),
  Var2 = sample(c(paste0(LETTERS[1:10],letters[10:18], letters[18:26], letters), paste0(letters[1:10],"bundle")), 100, replace = T),
  Var3 = sample(c(paste0(LETTERS[1:10],letters), paste0(letters[1:10],"bundle")), 100, replace = T))

head(df)
         Var1    Var2    Var3
1 -0.56047565    Irzi cbundle
2 -0.23017749 ibundle      Aa
3  1.55870831    Bmuv cbundle
4  0.07050839    Ijrs abundle
5  0.12928774    Eowo      Cw
6  1.71506499 fbundle      Hr
```

**Solution**:

Here we `paste0` all rows together, match all `bundle` strings using `grepl`, and subtract (`-`) those rows from the dataframe `which` match the pattern:

```
df[-which(grepl("bundle", apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse = " "))),]
```

**Result**:

If we store the subsetted dataframe as `df2`, the result is this:

```
df2 <- df[-which(grepl("bundle", apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse = " "))),]

head(df2)
         Var1 Var2 Var3
5   0.1292877 Eowo   Cw
7   0.4609162 Dnvn   Ff
8  -1.2650612 Aksk   Aa
9  -0.6868529 Gpxg   Gq
10 -0.4456620 Gpxg   Hr
11  1.2240818 Hrzr   Eo
```

**Note**:

This solution is helpful if the string to be matched is scattered across more than one column. If the  match occurs in just a single column, normal subsetting procedures will suffice.